# Iterate over not existing Azure resource manager (ARM) object properties?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I have object with not equal number of properties (and would like to keep it like this), i.e. second object is missing property "routeTable"

```
"subnets": {
"value":[
{
"name": "GatewaySubnet",
"addressPrefix": "10.2.0.0/24",
"networkSecurityGroup":"NSG-AllowAll",
"routeTable":"UDR-Default"
},
{
"name":"UnTrusted",
"addressPrefix":"10.2.1.0/24",
"networkSecurityGroup":"NSG-AllowAll",
}]}
```

Now I don't know how to check if property exists when iterating over object. The below gives error because of missing property **"id": "[resourceID('Microsoft.Network/routeTables', parameters('subnets')[copyIndex('subnets')].routeTable)]"**

My conditions for nested "id" property do not seem to work i.e.

```
"networkSecurityGroup": {
"id": "[resourceID('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', if(equals(parameters('subnets')[copyIndex('subnets')].networkSecurityGroup, ''), json('null'), parameters('subnets')[copyIndex('subnets')].networkSecurityGroup))]"
}
```

Comment: ok, i dont really understand, why do you show nsg condition, when routetable condition doesnt work? or this one doesnt work as well? and what is the endgoal? i think i get the idea, but i might wrong, are you trying to do a copy loop over subnets? and assign nsg\udr if they exist in parent object (and you iterate over parent object)?

Comment: The end goal is deploy subnet with NSG or UDR if they exist in params. It is possible and required that subnet is deployed with NSG only, without UDR or the other way around. Or even without any NSG or UDR. It works if I have UDR and NSG as properties for every subnet, but I don't like it as most subnet don't need at least one of them

Comment: i can try and figure something out, but its not going to be pretty either way. your best bet is building this outside of arm templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, this is the best I can come up with:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "deploymentPrefix": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "subnets": {
            "type": "array",
            "defaultValue": [
                {
                    "name": "GatewaySubnet",
                    "addressPrefix": "10.2.0.0/24",
                    "networkSecurityGroup": "NSG-AllowAll",
                    "routeTable": "UDR-Default"
                },
                {
                    "name": "UnTrusted",
                    "addressPrefix": "10.2.1.0/24",
                    "networkSecurityGroup": "NSG-AllowAll1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "routed",
                    "addressPrefix": "10.2.2.0/24",
                    "routeTable": "UDR-Default1"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "copy": [
            {
                "name": "subnetsBase",
                "count": "[length(parameters('subnets'))]",
                "input": {
                    "name": "[concat('subnet-', parameters('subnets')[copyIndex('subnetsBase')].name)]",
                    "properties": {
                        "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnets')[copyIndex('subnetsBase')].addressPrefix]"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "subnetsUDR",
                "count": "[length(parameters('subnets'))]",
                "input": {
                    "routeTable": {
                        "id": "[if(contains(parameters('subnets')[copyIndex('subnetsUDR')], 'routeTable'), resourceId('Microsoft.Network/routeTables', parameters('subnets')[copyIndex('subnetsUDR')].routeTable), 'skip')]"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "subnetsNSG",
                "count": "[length(parameters('subnets'))]",
                "input": {
                    "networkSecurityGroup": {
                        "id": "[if(contains(parameters('subnets')[copyIndex('subnetsNSG')], 'networkSecurityGroup'), resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('subnets')[copyIndex('subnetsNSG')].networkSecurityGroup), 'skip')]"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "condition": "[not(contains(variables('subnetsNSG')[copyIndex()].networkSecurityGroup.id, 'skip'))]",
            "apiVersion": "2017-06-01",
            "name": "[if(contains(parameters('subnets')[copyIndex()], 'networkSecurityGroup'), parameters('subnets')[copyIndex()].networkSecurityGroup, 'skip')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
            "copy": {
                "name": "nsg",
                "count": "[length(parameters('subnets'))]"
            },
            "properties": {
                "securityRules": []
            }
        },
        {
            "condition": "[not(contains(variables('subnetsUDR')[copyIndex()].routeTable.id, 'skip'))]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables",
            "name": "[if(contains(parameters('subnets')[copyIndex()], 'routeTable'), parameters('subnets')[copyIndex()].routeTable, 'skip')]",
            "apiVersion": "2017-10-01",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "copy": {
                "name": "udr",
                "count": "[length(parameters('subnets'))]"
            },
            "properties": {
                "routes": []
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2017-06-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('deploymentPrefix'), '-vNet')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "nsg",
                "udr"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "addressSpace": {
                    "addressPrefixes": [
                        "10.2.0.0/16"
                    ]
                },
                "copy": [
                    {
                        "name": "subnets",
                        "count": "[length(parameters('subnets'))]",
                        "input": {
                            "name": "[concat('subnet-', parameters('subnets')[copyIndex('subnets')].name)]",
                            "properties": "[union(variables('subnetsBase')[copyIndex('subnets')].properties, if(equals(variables('subnetsUDR')[copyIndex('subnets')].routetable.id, 'skip'), variables('subnetsBase')[copyIndex('subnets')].properties, variables('subnetsUDR')[copyIndex('subnets')]), if(equals(variables('subnetsNSG')[copyIndex('subnets')].networkSecurityGroup.id, 'skip'), variables('subnetsBase')[copyIndex('subnets')].properties, variables('subnetsNSG')[copyIndex('subnets')]))]"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

you can probably make it better with some nested loops. but this works as well.

PS. I had use different names for nsg\udr as I am creating those dynamically, in your scenario if those exists it will work with identical names (this wont).

Comment: Actually it's looking great, let me just test it and I will come back

Comment: when I add new subnet i.e. ,
                {
                    "name": "routed2",
                    "addressPrefix": "10.2.3.0/24",
                    "routeTable": "UDR-Default1"
                }
it says Deployment template validation failed: 'The resource 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/skip' at line '1' and column '1576' is defined multipletimes in a template. .'.

Comment: yes, i've mentioned that, names have to be different, because I create udr\nsg in the same template, you can easily work around that using nesteds

Comment: Sorry, not sure what I should nest, move vnet to deployments ?

Comment: not that i think about it, maybe its not that easy to achieve that, but you certainly can. but this is really out of scope of the question. the question is how to use "jagged" objects to iterate over them. if you need help with your new question - please raise another one ;)