# How to use "jagged" objects in Azure Resource Manger templates to iterate over them?

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I have object with not equal number of properties (and would like to keep it like this), i.e. second object is missing property "routeTable" and properties repeat i.e. "NSG-AllowAll"

```
"value": [
                {
                    "name": "GatewaySubnet",
                    "addressPrefix": "10.2.0.0/24",
                    "networkSecurityGroup": "NSG-AllowAll",
                    "routeTable": "UDR-Default"
                },
                {
                    "name": "UnTrusted",
                    "addressPrefix": "10.2.1.0/24",
                    "networkSecurityGroup": "NSG-AllowAll"
                },
                {
                    "name": "routed",
                    "addressPrefix": "10.2.2.0/24",
                    "routeTable": "UDR-Default1"
                }
            ]
```

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54277322/iterate-over-not-existing-azure-resource-manager-arm-object-properties/54278741?noredirect=1#comment95402043_54278741) to create vnet works fine but only if exisiting properties don't repeat i.e. the second NSG above has different name from the first one. In my scenario there will be a lot of repeating property names

Comment: ok, so just to clarify, you only need to create vnet with subnets?

Comment: Correct, create vnet with subnets which are assigned routes (udr) and/or (nsg) security groups (or no routes or security groups at all), names or udr/nsg can repeat

Comment: yeah, but you dont need to create nsg\udr, right? they exist already

Comment: I think we can assume that nsg/udr exist already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case you just need to remove nsg\udr from that template I've created. I think thats what I've told you there as well. check the `ps` in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54278741/6067741).

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "deploymentPrefix": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "subnets": {
            "type": "array",
            "defaultValue": [
                {
                    "name": "GatewaySubnet",
                    "addressPrefix": "10.2.0.0/24",
                    "networkSecurityGroup": "NSG-AllowAll",
                    "routeTable": "UDR-Default"
                },
                {
                    "name": "UnTrusted",
                    "addressPrefix": "10.2.1.0/24",
                    "networkSecurityGroup": "NSG-AllowAll"
                },
                {
                    "name": "routed",
                    "addressPrefix": "10.2.2.0/24",
                    "routeTable": "UDR-Default"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "copy": [
            {
                "name": "subnetsBase",
                "count": "[length(parameters('subnets'))]",
                "input": {
                    "name": "[concat('subnet-', parameters('subnets')[copyIndex('subnetsBase')].name)]",
                    "properties": {
                        "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnets')[copyIndex('subnetsBase')].addressPrefix]"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "subnetsUDR",
                "count": "[length(parameters('subnets'))]",
                "input": {
                    "routeTable": {
                        "id": "[if(contains(parameters('subnets')[copyIndex('subnetsUDR')], 'routeTable'), resourceId('Microsoft.Network/routeTables', parameters('subnets')[copyIndex('subnetsUDR')].routeTable), 'skip')]"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "subnetsNSG",
                "count": "[length(parameters('subnets'))]",
                "input": {
                    "networkSecurityGroup": {
                        "id": "[if(contains(parameters('subnets')[copyIndex('subnetsNSG')], 'networkSecurityGroup'), resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('subnets')[copyIndex('subnetsNSG')].networkSecurityGroup), 'skip')]"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2017-06-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('deploymentPrefix'), '-vNet')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "properties": {
                "addressSpace": {
                    "addressPrefixes": [
                        "10.2.0.0/16"
                    ]
                },
                "copy": [
                    {
                        "name": "subnets",
                        "count": "[length(parameters('subnets'))]",
                        "input": {
                            "name": "[concat('subnet-', parameters('subnets')[copyIndex('subnets')].name)]",
                            "properties": "[union(variables('subnetsBase')[copyIndex('subnets')].properties, if(equals(variables('subnetsUDR')[copyIndex('subnets')].routetable.id, 'skip'), variables('subnetsBase')[copyIndex('subnets')].properties, variables('subnetsUDR')[copyIndex('subnets')]), if(equals(variables('subnetsNSG')[copyIndex('subnets')].networkSecurityGroup.id, 'skip'), variables('subnetsBase')[copyIndex('subnets')].properties, variables('subnetsNSG')[copyIndex('subnets')]))]"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I dont see any reason why this wont work if you have nsg\udr in place